# Install spring ide in eclipse

Tags: spring, spring-security

Is it necessary to install `spring ide` in eclipse  to use spring security in a web application jsf2.0, although I added all the necessary `.jar`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can make a spring application without the ide installed. The ide just makes developing with spring easier with things like Advanced code completion, content-assist, validation, ... etc.